# How to build ONLY some projects during gradle build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I am not gradle expert. Used to work on ant and maven. I have around 10 projects. All of them gets built when I do

```
$gradle.

defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
```

build is one of defaultTask. Now, I want that by default only some of the projects should get built ! I also want to create another task buildAll which will build all projects.

Any help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom task to run the build of only specified subprojects, for example:

```
def commonBuilds = [
        ':Project1:build',
        ':Project2:build'
]

task buildSpecifiedProjects(dependsOn: commonBuilds) {

}
```

Here is the `buildSpecifiedProjects` task in the root project, which will build only the projects you've provided in the `commonBuilds` (note, task name is provided with the module name - `:Project1:build`)

To build all projects, you can still use the `build` task of the root project.